# Reuse same prometheus alarm across multiple labels

Tags: prometheus

I have set up a Prometheus alarm based on the following query-
`sum(rate(jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{datacenter=~"London", service="my-service", cause="G1 Evacuation Pause"}[5m])) > 100`

Now I have multiple regions where I want to use the same alarm. I want to avoid typing the same alarm multiple times with changing the datacenter each time. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it by using alterations in regex selector for you expression:

```
sum(rate(jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{datacenter=~"London|Paris|Berlin", service="my-service", cause="G1 Evacuation Pause"}[5m])) > 100
```

Basic examples of querying in Prometheus listed in [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors).

Comment: I tried this but the query pulls data for each datacenter and sum function just sums it all up. This is not what I want.

Comment: @Sankalp, seems like I misunderstood you question then. If you need to sum by datacenter - use Vladimir's solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want alert on all datacenters just move datacenter label from timeseries definition to `sum()` function:

```
sum by (datacenter) (rate(jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{service="my-service", cause="G1 Evacuation Pause"}[5m])) > 100
```

Beware that in case there are series without datacenter label in source, they will also trigger alert.

Otherwise (if you only want to alert on subset of datacenters) just filter by list of particular datacenters as @markalex suggested.